# Laravel project shows flash of html without css on first load

Tags: css, laravel, loading, preloader

I have a Laravel project.  When I load, it shows just HTML flash first then load CSS with little delay.  How can I fix this?

I tried preloader but it shows flash and then preloader means there is still a little flash of simple HTML between preloader.

I tried this in header file:

```
<div class="preloader"></div>
<script>
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('.preloader').fadeOut('slow');
    });
```

CSS:

```
.preloader {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    background-image: url("../img/loader.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #FFF;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Place your rest of code other than preloader inside some container, by default make that container style as `display:none` and as your preloader fades make that container style `display:block`

Comment: I'm using this in header file where all CCC and JS files also

Comment: @farooq can you explain in details, i did not understand properly.

Comment: i added preload to hidd delay . 
or Other solution i got to minify CSS and JS